# Can't edit files in /sys/ folder

Tags: buttons, backlight

Is there any way to edit files in sys folder? I want to do that because buttons backlight on new rom is off, probably because I turned it off on previous rom and now I dont have backlight buttons settings.

Comment: /sys or /system? /sys is the sysfs psuedo filesystem which is a reflection of the kernel's device object structure and should not (cannot?) be edited directly even with root access.

Comment: @acejavelin /sys OK. Well than how it was possible to change brightness when it's file is stored there?

Comment: Doesn't Lux work? BTW, it's file isn't stored there, the current setting the kernel is using would be... the actual brightness is somewhere in the framework (beyond my direct knowledge).

Comment: It works, but I wanted to do it without aditional apps. Oh, my bad than. Thanks anyway

Comment: From my experience, editing it is possible at least on some occasions. Many HTC devices rely on the trick to disable/enable capacitive key backlights. Problem is you don't know what devices are capable of that and what files they allow you to touch - Samsung phones save those in a different place (device) for example. If editing directly fails, try writing an init.d script that does the same on boot (via echo).